# Markers for Blank Exhibition Space and Better Tracking for Google Tango

Tags: google-project-tango

If i am in a blank exhibition room with the tango w white walls and not a lot of architectural features, is it better to add markers around the room to help the tango track its position better?

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the question. Yes if you are in a room with lots of white walls or generally areas without much texture, you can improve performance by adding some texture. It doesn't need to be markers per se, but anything that adds some visual structure. Adding a poster or two onto a wall is usually enough to provide the visual constraints needed for tracking in that area.

Comment: Is there is a way to use a physical landmark so that if the tango “looks” at the landmark, the tango can recalibrate its origin point in the virtual world?  I’m finding that if the tango loses its tracking, when it recovers, its position in the virtual world is shifted.